# Getting "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service" while trying to send message in .net

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am trying to send notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1).

This the action method which is used to send the message.

```
    [HttpPost("notification")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage(SingleMessageRequest request)
    {
        var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
        if (messaging == null)
        {
            notificationService.GetFirebaseApp();
            messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
        }

        var message = new Message()
        {
            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                ["Name"] = request.data.Name,
                ["Email"] = request.data.Email
            },
            Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification
            {
                Title = request.notification.title,
                Body = request.notification.body
            },
            Token = request.token,
            //Topic = request.topic
        };

        var result = await messaging.SendAsync(message);
        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }
```

Here `notificationService.GetFirebaseApp();` is the method for setting up firebase configuration in seperate service.

```
    public interface INotificationService
    {
        public FirebaseApp GetFirebaseApp();
    }

    public class NotificationService : INotificationService
    {
        public FirebaseApp GetFirebaseApp()
        {
            var credentials = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "key.json")),
            });

            return credentials;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fvrG.png)

This is the secretKey.json file generated from the account.

From the React App I am using the same project config details. And also able to generate the device token. But when I am trying to send message using the .net api project it is giving me the error "**Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service**".

I have checked all the permission and other stuff but this account has all the permission.

Not I am not able to find the cause here. Can anyone help me here please?

Thanks

Error :

```
FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndReadAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndDeserializeAsync[TResult](HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message)
   at FirebaseCloudMessagingPOC.Controllers.NotificationController.SendMessage(SingleMessageRequest request) in C:\Users\Vijay.Parmar\source\repos\FirebaseCloudMessagingPOC\FirebaseCloudMessagingPOC\Controllers\NotificationController.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4JtN.png)

Comment: Try deleting cookies.  You may of changed code.  Looks like from error there is an existing authorization and isn't accepting you new token.

Comment: I'm having similar error. have you found the problem yet? @vijay-parmar I have android side working, but iOS is having this error in one of our environments. some envs do still work, which is odd. I'm thinking some setup has been made different or is missing.

Comment: was this resolved?  I also have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing cookies did the job for me.